# How do I get the record ID of the record with the min date for each foreign key?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following table

```
recordID               createdDate                         ForeignKeyID
00QA000000PtFXaMAN     2012-01-03 13:23:36.000             001A000000ngM21IAE
00QA000000OS2QiMAL     2011-12-15 12:03:02.000             001A000000ngM21IAE
.
.
.
.
```

I am trying to get the recordID for foreignKeyID where createdDAte is the min(createdDate) for foreignKeyID

if recordID is identity int I can get that by doing the following query

```
Select min(recordId),ForeignkeyID
from table 
group by ForeignKeyId
```

I originaly thought that I can create temp table with the following query and then joining it to table on minDate and foreignKeyID but then I found out that there are multiple records for foreignKeyId that has the same exact createdDate.

```
Select min(createdDate) as minDate,ForeignKeyID
from table
group by ForeignKeyId
```

I'm open with using temp table or subquery or anything really. Thanks.

Comment: This question has been answered many times in the past: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group+sql-server

Comment: @BillKarwin Thanks for pointing that out, I was having difficulty in trying to figure out how to search for the questions.  I tried few but didn't come up with what I needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the ways to do it is

```
select A.ForeignKeyID, R.recordID
from (select distinct t.ForeignKeyID from table as t) as A
    outer apply
    (
        select top 1 t.recordID
        from table as t where t.ForeignKeyID = A.ForeignKeyID
        order by t.createdDate asc
    ) as R
```

[**SQL FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/755c5/7)

Another way to do it is

```
select top 1 with ties
    t.recordID, t.ForeignKeyID
from table as t
order by row_number() over (partition by t.ForeignKeyID order by t.createdDate)
```

[**SQL FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/755c5/5)

And another way

```
select A.recordID, A.ForeignKeyID
from
(
    select
        t.recordID, t.ForeignKeyID,
        row_number() over (partition by t.ForeignKeyID order by t.createdDate) as RowNum
    from table1 as t
) as A
where A.RowNum = 1
```

[**SQL FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/755c5/10)

I like second one more than others because of shortness of code

Comment: Wow @roman thank you very much.  The first one worked great and I will checkout the other 2.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
    recordID, createdDate, ForeignKeyID
FROM
  ( SELECT 
        recordID, createdDate, ForeignKeyID,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY ForeignKeyID 
                            ORDER BY createdDate, recordID
                          ) AS rn
    FROM 
        tableX
  ) AS t
WHERE 
    rn = 1 ;
```

Comment: It was very helpful for me. Thanks