# How to select distinct rows with a specified condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose there is a table

```
_ _
a 1
a 2
b 2
c 3
c 4
c 1
d 2
e 5
e 6
```

How can I select distinct minimum value of all the rows of each group?

So the expected result here is:

```
_ _
a 1
b 2
c 1
d 2
e 5
```

**EDIT**

My actual table contains more columns and I want to select them all. The rows differ only in the last column (the second one in the example). I'm new to SQL and possibly my question is ill-formed in it initial view.

The actual schema is:

```
| day | currency ('EUR', 'USD') | diff (integer) | id (foreign key) |
```

The are duplicate pairs `(day, currency)` that differ by `(diff, id)`. I want to see a table with uniquer pairs `(day, currency)` with a minimum `diff` from the original table.

Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

in your case it's as simple as this:

```
select column1, min(column2) as column2
from table
group by column1
```

for more than two columns I can suggest this:

```
select top 1 with ties
    t.column1, t.column2, t.column3
from table as t
order by row_number() over (partition by t.column1 order by t.column2)
```

take a look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/13652861/1744834

Comment: I tried this approach (except for my actual table contains more columns), but it just gave me all rows

Comment: well this approach is good for two columns. I'll add my favourite approach for more than two columns in a second

Comment: @Andrew Can you please update your original post with your actual schema and all the rows you want to select?

Comment: @Andrew And what do you want to see as the result of the query?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the ranking function [**`ROW_NUMBER()`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) to do this with a CTE. Especially, if there are more column other than these two column, it will give the distict values like so:

```
;WITH RankedCTE
AS
(
   SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY column1 ORDER BY Colmn2 ) rownum
   FROM Table
)
SELECT column1, column2
FROM RankedCTE
WHERE rownum = 1;
```

This will give you:

```
COLUMN1   COLUMN2
   a         1
   b         2
   c         1
   d         2
   e         5
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/90b02/2)

Comment: This is beyond overkill for his use case.

Comment: @DigitalD I wanted to add this comment, but then it turns out that OP had more than 2 columns so this approach is actually useful for him

Comment: @RomanPekar I see that now. He didn't specify that infomation initially

Answer (score 1):

SELECT ColOne, Min(ColTwo)
 FROM Table 
GROUP BY ColOne
ORDER BY ColOne

PS: not front of a,machine, but give above a try please.

Answer (score 1):

```
select MIN(col2),col1
from dbo.Table_1
group by col1
```