# Remove duplicate rows based on composite key and keep the latest row entry mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table "orders" contains 3 fields id, user_id and order_id

[image]

I want to remove the row having user_id and order_id same, and the row with greater id would not be deleted which is id = 3 in this scenario.
So the result would be looking like this,
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select distinct rows with a specified condition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13667457/how-to-select-distinct-rows-with-a-specified-condition)

Comment: There are thousands of rows repeated in original table, so it would take much time, is there any other alternate solution?

Comment: No not really. It all comes down to duplicate elimination which is expensive from a theoretic point of view. If you can make any assumptions how your data looks like you can tweak the algorithm a bit. Having indices on user_id, order_id would help, too. But this does not change the complexity of the underlying problem. Try it out, and if it's too slow, open another, more detailed question.

Comment: I have the problem with storing data, I don't want to store duplicate data in mysql table, how to prevent from storing duplicate records?
non repeated records can be easily fetched from DB.

Comment: Maybe this is what you need, although this is a totally different question: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: I think it would be better to insert duplicate records and then run delete query to remove duplicate records based recent id.

Comment: @flowit Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First duplicate record should be inserted and then delete the duplicate record.

```
DELETE n1 FROM orders n1, orders n2 WHERE n1.id < n2.id AND n1.user_id = n2.user_id AND n1.order_id = n2.order_id;
```