# Select distinct from condition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am having trouble getting the correct syntax for a `select distinct` statement.

I can't figure out the correct code to get what I need from this link.

- [How to select distinct rows with a specified condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13667457/how-to-select-distinct-rows-with-a-specified-condition) and
- [How do I get the record ID of the record with the min date for each foreign key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13652828/how-do-i-get-the-record-id-of-the-record-with-the-min-date-for-each-foreign-key/13652861#13652861)

This is the code I have now, but it obviously selects multiple dates, when I want the `SELECT DISTINCT` applied just to `column1`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    column1, column2, column3, column4, column5
FROM Table1
WHERE 
    column1 >= '2016/1/1' 
    And column1 < '2016/1/4' 
    AND column2 = 1 
    AND column3 = 1 
ORDER BY column2, column1;
```

This is what I put together in [Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f6770/1), but again this selects multiple same dates in `column1`. Honestly, I don't even know where to begin with constructing this statement from those links.

Sorry, I linked to SQL Sever 2008 from Fiddle, I am using 2014.

EDIT: Add more information,
 This is the results I am getting now:

```
January, 01 2016 00:00:00   1   1   1   4
January, 01 2016 00:00:00   1   1   5   4
January, 01 2016 00:00:00   1   1   9   4
January, 02 2016 00:00:00   1   1   2   4
January, 02 2016 00:00:00   1   1   6   4
January, 03 2016 00:00:00   1   1   3   4
January, 03 2016 00:00:00   1   1   7   4
```

This is the results I am looking for:

```
January, 01 2016 00:00:00   1   1   1   4
January, 02 2016 00:00:00   1   1   2   4
January, 03 2016 00:00:00   1   1   7   4
```

Comment: I can't open your Fiddle. Could you include it in the question?

Comment: Do you want something like this?
`SELECT column1, column2, column3, column4, column5
FROM TABLE1
WHERE COLUMN1 IN (SELECT DISTINCT column1 FROM TABLE1 WHERE column1 >= '2016/1/1' And column1 < '2016/1/4')
   AND column2 = 1 AND column3 = 1 
ORDER BY column2, column1;`

Comment: @S.Karras That is not working for me, I still get multiple same dates from `column1`.

Comment: Ok now I am beginning to see what you want. Let me ask you something. For those distinct values of column1, what data do you want to see? For example if I have twice `column1 = '2016/1/1'` with different values for the other columns which set do you want your query to return?

Comment: @S.Karras What I am trying to do is get Unique date values from `column1`. ie, if there was two sets of identical data in each day of January, I would get 31 sets of data (for each day of January) where the data in  `column1`, `column2`, `column3` are the same.

Comment: For `2016/1/3` is it really `7` for `column4`???

Comment: @Ullas The data in `column4` could be anything, which is why I am getting multiple data-sets with the same date.  If the data was all the same in all the other columns a normal `SELECT DISTINCT` would work.

Comment: Why choose `January, 03 2016 00:00:00   1   1   7   4` over `January, 03 2016 00:00:00   1   1   3   4` or `January, 02 2016 00:00:00   1   1   2   4` over `January, 02 2016 00:00:00   1   1   6   4` ?

Comment: @S.Karras In the real database the SQL Statement can arbitrarily select either of those data-sets as long as the criteria meets what is needed in `column2` and `column3` and is the same date in `column1`. There will only ever be a max of 3 rows of data-sets with the same date data in `column1`.

Comment: How about this one: `;WITH DistinctDate 
AS
(  SELECT column1,column2, column3, column4, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY COLUMN1 ORDER BY column2, column1) AS RowNumber
   FROM TABLE1
   WHERE column1 >= '2016/1/1' 
    AND column1 < '2016/1/4'
)
SELECT  column1,column2, column3, column4
FROM DistinctDate
WHERE RowNumber = 1 AND column2 = 1  AND column3 = 1  ;`

Comment: @S.Karras can't get that working on the real DB or in SQL Fiddle.

Comment: @S.Karras Thanks, I finally got everything working great. Really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a classic `top-n-per-group` problem.

One possible option is to use `ROW_NUMBER`. You need to decide which row should be picked for each unique value of the `column1` by specifying `ORDER BY` in the `OVER` clause.

```
WITH
CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        column1, column2, column3, column4, column5
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY column1 ORDER BY ...) AS rn
    FROM Table1
    WHERE 
        column1 >= '2016/1/1' 
        And column1 < '2016/1/4' 
        AND column2 = 1 
        AND column3 = 1 
)
SELECT
    column1, column2, column3, column4, column5
FROM CTE
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY column2, column1;
```

See [Retrieving n rows per group](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/86415/retrieving-n-rows-per-group) for detailed comparison of several methods.

Comment: what do you put after the `ORDER BY ...` ?

Comment: @JapanDave, it depends on which row you want to pick for each group. For example, if you want to pick a row with the smallest value in `column2`, then `ORDER BY column2`. If you don't care which row to pick you can `ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)`.

Comment: Sorry, I may have confused you, I want all the data in `column1` . I think I have miss led you somewhat, I did not realize that the data types would make a difference, `column2` is actually a nvarchar and I am trying to get all data matched to that. It should be `column2 = 'myName'` . For the sake of the question, you have answered it, but my explanation is lacking, I am really sorry.

Comment: @JapanDave, I didn't really understand your previous comment, but I'm glad that you managed to solve your problem.

Comment: I gave incorrect data type in my question on one of the columns which is vital to how the statement is written.